# Looping through Foreach, calling results inside of if statement

Tags: php

How can I return the data which is presented inside of this `foreach` element, inside of my `if` statement, which comes after the initial foreach.

```
foreach ($arr as $line) { 
   print $line;
}
```

When we print `$line` it should return something like this.

```
Example 1
Example 2
Example 3
Example 4
```

I want to call each element from line, to be set inside of this `if` statement, but only if the statement contains a specific word.

```
$status_check = $_GET['status'];
if (strpos($status, 'online') !== false) {
  print $line; // return all of the contents from the (foreach) here.
}
```

Comment: Do you mean copy the `if` statement to be inside the loop?

Comment: So you only want to return the lines (eg Example 1, Example 2, etc ) if the `$_GET['status']` contains `online`?

Comment: @OliGirling I want to return those lines inside of the `if` statement, when `$_GET['status']` contains `online` the issue is, I am doing this as a way of creating WordPress posts, so I have to load my `if` statement outside of the initial `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you need to return the data of the array outside of the foreach loop so you dont need to use one.

```
if (strpos($_GET['status'], 'online') !== false) {
    print array_values($arr);
}
```

Will return:

```
Example 1
Example 2
Example 3
Example 4
```

Only if `$_GET['status']` contains `online`